# Inheriting width of a select element

Tags: html, css, width, html-table

I have a select element within a table cell. I would like the select to inherit the width from the  element so it doesn't overflow in the normal state.

When a user selects an "option", it's okay for the box to expand to the width of the maximum element.
I tried setting 
    max-width:inherit;
But I read somewhere that this would work only if the width property of the parent element is set.
Could someone point out the correct way of doing this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `select` element inherit the `width` property from its parent (in this case, a `td` element) by setting `width: inherit` on it. This means that it inherits the computed value of the CSS property `width`, not the actual width.

Table column width is complicated, especially since it often involves using the width requirements of cell contents. But the following (too) simple example demonstrates how inheritance can be used:

```
<table border>
<tr><td style="width: 100px">
<select style="width: inherit">
<option>Supercalifralisticexpialidocious
</select>
</table>
```

This will make the width of the `select` element the same as its parent’s, i.e. 100 pixels. There is not much point in doing things that way instead of setting it directly to the desired value, but if there are several cells with different widths containing `select` elements to be restricted to that width, `width: inherit` can be handy. You can alternatively set `width: 100%`.

Comment: Well the thing is I can not set the width of the <td> element.And if I do not set that value, using "width:inherit" isn't working.